# Store file pointer, and reset to that position based on condition?

Tags: c++

I am not able to understand how I can reset the file pointer to a previously stored position.

Here is the actual problem in pseudocode:

I am reading characters from a file `f` in some function A (B and C are some other functions):

```cpp
      void A (fstream& f) {
        char c = f.get();
        while (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
          c = f.get();
        while ( !<C> ) {
          B(c);          
          c = f.get();
          while (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
            c = f.get(); 
        }
        C(c);
        return;
      }
```

where the condition `\<C>` is that if c is the start with the regex:

```
     TT WS* ::=
```

where

```
    WS = {' ', '\n'}
```

it should return true, and the file pointer to f must still point to the first `T` in this regex. How do I implement `\<C>` as another function?

Clearly to read the regex, I need to increment the file pointer, but then I need to reset it to the first `T`, how do I do this?

Comment: There is no space between TT and WS, and WS and ::= in the regex.

Comment: What is `c`? Where is it defined? Pseudo-code is not helping here at all.

Comment: @tadman: edited

Comment: Why not read everything into a single buffer and skip around using pointers instead of mashing around with fstream operations? This looks like something you can do by splitting the string into tokens and then dealing with the components.

Comment: That's an approach, thanks!

Comment: I mean it's kind of low-tech, but that's how parsers have been written in C since the 1970s. You could also write a slightly higher-level wrapper that emits tokens as it reads through the string, but at that point you're effectively re-inventing tools like [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/).

Comment: @Kaind If your lookahead requirement is only one character then you can use `peek`. It reads a character without changing the file position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::istream` descendants, including `std::fstream`, have [`tellg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [`seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) methods for querying and setting the stream's input position, respectively.